# Polynomial Linest fit with multiple x inputs for the same y

Tags: excel, data-fitting

How can I fit a polynomial in excel with multiple X values for the same Y? eg:

```
Line 1: Y knows (a set of *n* columns of data) eg: from A to M. Range: A1:M1
Line 2: X (same number of items of line 1). Range: A2:M2
```

This will fit a 2nd order polynomial to this data:

```
LINEST(A1:M1;A2:M2^TRANSPOSE({1\2}))
```

But how I can do that with multiple Xs for each Y, eg:

```
Line 1: Y knows
Line 2: X. Range: A2:M2
Line 3: X2. Range: A3:M3
Line 4: X3. Range: A3:M3
```

X total range: A2:M4

LINEST(A1:M1;A2:M4^TRANSPOSE({1\2})) wont work.

I was able to fit it by manually coping the data to the same line, eg:

```
Line 1: Y knows | repeat Y knows | repeat Y knows
Line 2: X | X2 | X3. Range: A2:AM2
```

eg: if Y = { 1 10 20 }. Line 1 would be: 1 10 20 1 10 20 1 10 20.

But I have too much data, and copy "by hand" or a macro is not an option.

Comment: Not clear.......are your **x** values in a *column* and the **y** values in a *row?*

Comment: I don't quite understand what's wrong with having `f(x1) = f(x2) = f(x3)`.. (Ie : Sin() function gives infinite Xs points for the same Y values) **OR** are you saying that you have 1 cell for Y and multiple Xs? If that is, then you need to fill the number of cells for it to work properly.. Your problem is not really clear.

Comment: @Sifu, I'm saying that I have for each Y multiples Xs.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Question edited. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: So your data is something along this : `Ys{4,4,4,6,6,6} Xs{1,2,3,4,5,6}`? You could try this `LINEST(TRANSPOSE(A1:M1);TRANSPOSE(A2:M2))`

Comment: @Sifu, I'm already able to do it for only one X set of data, as described on the question. LINEST(A1:M1;A2:M2^TRANSPOSE({1\2})).